# Scipy normal PDF summing to values larger than 1

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, probability-density

I'm working with `scipy.stats.norm` PDFs. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong (maybe yes), since the sum of the PDF over the normal distribution is returning values larger than one, and, by definition, a probability density function should sum up to 1. I would be ok if it would sum up to ~0.99 (since I'm not summing all values in the interval) but 20 isn't much acceptable. A minimum example is shown below

```
from scipy.stats import norm
lower_bound = norm.ppf(0.01)
upper_bound = norm.ppf(0.99)
N = 100
x = np.linspace(lower_bound, upper_bound, 100)
P = norm.pdf(x) 
print(np.sum(P))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your definition should be tweaked slightly: by definition, *the integral* of the probability density function over the entire space should be equal to 1. If you want to approximate this integral using a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), you should multiply the values by the spacing between your `x` values. You will then see that the result is much closer to 1:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
>>> lower_bound = norm.ppf(0.01)
>>> upper_bound = norm.ppf(0.99)
>>> N = 100
>>> x, step = np.linspace(lower_bound, upper_bound, N, retstep=True)
>>> P = norm.pdf(x)
>>> print(np.sum(P * step))
0.9812297466603901
```

The exact result (which you can more closely approximate by increasing `N`) should be `0.98`, the difference between the `q` values passed to `norm.ppf`.

Comment: indeed. integral. Your definition is the correct one. Thanks.